# Passing parameters in hug server as /foo/something in double number function

Tags: routes, hug

I want to get the double of one number when I access to URL `/double/<number>` in hug server. Something like [routing](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#variable-rules) in flask. Is it possible to do that? In [documentation of hug server](http://www.hug.rest/website/learn/routing), I did not found nothing:

My code would seem like:

```
@hug.get('/double', number)
def doubles(n):
    return 2*n
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, you can do:

```
import hug

@hug.get("/double/{number}")
def doubles(response, number: hug.types.number):
    return 2 * number
```

Note, that if you don't define type it will default to `string`.

Comment: How can I define the type of the variable of the method? How can I pass `{number}` to be a `path`, that is string which accepts slashes

Comment: Not sure you can do a string that accepts slashes that since slash `/` is a special delimiter for hug. You can define a preset number of multiple parameters instead:


    `@hug.get("/double/{number}/{not_number}/{also_not_number}")`


    `def doubles(response, number: hug.types.number, not_number: hug.types.text, also_not_number: hug.types.text):`
        `return 2 * number, not_number, also_not_number`

Comment: I have a feeling that this would be easier if you explained with an example of an URL you are trying to get.

Comment: Can you specify the path type like flask? For example returns the content of plain text file passing path of that: [in pseudocode] `def content(path): returns os.file(path).read`

Comment: Like a subpath? You want to catch `http://localhost:8000/foo` and `http://localhost:8000/foo/bar` and `http://localhost:8000/foo/bar/baz` all with one endpoint? Yeah, not sure that is possible with hug. Maybe by defining your own type that can take `/` as part of an argument. You would need to prevent hug's default mechanism of splitting the url by slashes.

Comment: perhaps we could ask as independent question

Comment: asked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59234007/passing-path-like-string-in-hug-server