# Passing path like string in hug server

Tags: routes, hug

Is there any way to pass a string with slashes in hug, for example with this function:

```
import hug

@hug.get("/returnfilecontent/{path}")
def doubles(path):
    return open(path, 'r').read()
```

I want to access to `http://localhost/returnfilecontent/foo/bar/myfile.md` to read contents from file located in `foo/bar/myfile.md`.

It seems hug does not [behave well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59193963/passing-parameters-in-hug-server-as-foo-something-in-double-number-function/59210515?noredirect=1#comment104655558_59210515) with paths and I can only pass non-path strings like `http://localhost/returnfilecontent/myfile.md`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether this is what you are looking for, May be this helps

```py
import hug

@hug.get("/returnfilecontent")
def doubles(request, path: hug.types.text):
    return open(path, 'r').read()
```

You can call this get request by

```sh
curl http://localhost:8000/returnfilecontent/\?path\=foo\/bar\/myfile.md
```

Or you can try passing in those as foo_bar_myfile.md and split and join it to make it a path

or like this

```py
import hug

@hug.get("/returnfilecontent/{base_path}/{middle_folder}/{filename}")
def doubles(request, base_path: hug.types.text, middle_folder, filename):
    return f"{base_path}/{middle_folder}/{filename}"
```

Comment: Mmm. This is not exactly what I want. I think I want to create a path-like string with [this](http://www.hug.rest/website/learn/type_annotation)

Comment: `?path\=foo\/bar\/myfile.md` does not work for me. Please verify answers.

Comment: I was using **curl** for that. You can get what ever you send in as path inside function